# Sudden loss of wifi control, how can I fix?

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, xubuntu, network-manager

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.3, and after connecting another SATA drive and restarting to get it detected (PnP doesn't seem to work), after the restart, I seem to have completely lost wifi support, which may have been from an update during the 19-day uptime...

Typically when opening the network-manager indicator plugin, you would have an option to "Enable Wireless", which I'd been connected with on this machine I'm typing with for some time...
But you can see I no longer have that here:
[image]

Where it says I'm connected through ethernet is actually a slower wifi (~30Mbps) connection through my secondary machine vs what I originally had (~115Mbps) through my USB wifi adapter.

Also just for notes, the wifi adapter ([Netgear AC600](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-adapters/A6100.aspx) piece of junk) is still connected, and reinstalling the driver (`$ sudo make install`, dealt with on numerous occasions) isn't working this time, so I think the problem is likely some automated update that destroyed everything.

How could I fix this??
What commands do you need to know to help me fix this??

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0151 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device (Multicard Reader)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c00c Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 007: ID ffff:ffff  
Bus 002 Device 005: ID ffff:ffff  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 19fa:8d91 Gampaq Co.Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Also, I think the preferred sequence is:`make clean` then: `make` and finally: `sudo make install`

Comment: that was the secret sauce, `make clean`, thanks for that, maybe I just got so caught up re-doing `sudo make install` that I forgot about the updates to the kernel sources, thanks again, I'll be sure to remember that from now on. ;)

Comment: So, you are all set? Fixed?

Comment: yep, all set: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/98580359909773312/416693486830616576/fixed_wifi.png gave it a restart after installing just to be safe, and that's when everything worked. ;)